# What is wrong with my zone records and name server configuration? My domain name isn't resolving

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, nameserver

I've moved to Amazon Route 53 as my registrar, but my domain ([kellshaw.com](https://kellshaw.com)) isn't resolving. However the website is up, as I can see it via the IP address.

According to infoDNS it's to do with the name servers:

- NS records from your nameserver -NS records got from your nameservers listed at the parent NS are: Oups! I could not get any nameservers from your nameservers (the ones listed at the parent server). Please verify that they are not lame nameservers and are configured properly.
- Mismatched NS records WARNING: One or more of your nameservers did not return any of your NS records.
- Multiple Nameservers  ERROR: Looks like you have less than 2 nameservers. According to RFC2182 section 5 you must have at least 3 nameservers, and no more than 7. Having 2 nameservers is also ok by me.

However, the NS and SOA records were autogenerated by Route 53. And the NS records match the ones on the Hosted Zone page. Here are the nameserver related records from the zone. (I haven't included the mail-related stuff.)

| Record | Type | Value | TTL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| kellshaw.com | A | 12.34.56.78 | 300 |
| @.kellshaw.com | A | 12.34.56.78 | 300 |
| kellshaw.com | NS | ns-687.awsdns-21.net. ns-1815.awsdns-34.co.uk. ns-390.awsdns-48.com. ns-1291.awsdns-33.org. | 172800 |
| kellshaw.com | SOA | ns-687.awsdns-21.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400 | 900 |

The other odd thing is that the nameservers reported by the parent servers appear to change every so often (according to https://intodns.com/)

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: If you have a look at https://intodns.com/kellshaw.com it appears that there are no A records.  You should contact cloudflare tech support

Answer (score 3):

I've solved this - <https://www.epiphanydigest.com/2019/05/16/how-to-actually-change-nameservers-for-a-route-53-domain/> Route 53 nameserver updates are in another part of the console to the main zone list.

1. In the AWS Route 53 console, I selected Hosted Zones
2. Under the zone records, I copied the nameservers given under the autogenerated NS record.
3. Next, I selected Domains>Registered domains. I clicked on my domain name.
4. Under Actions, I selected Edit Name servers. Then I replaced those default nameservers with the ones from the Hosted Zone NS record.

And now the website works. Thanks, I'll look at the other issues (A records, SSL) but now the domain is resolving.